# How to increment the value of a structure with multiple thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, queue

i want to increment the value of a counter stored in a structure. 3 threads are coming into the fonction tattoo_shop to increment the number of people but for some reasons the value of number_of_people remain the same.

I tried to reproduce the case sequentially and it's working. Is there something special to do as i'm working with threads ? Thank you :)

```
typedef struct {
    int number_of_people;
}Queue;

void *tattoo_shop(void *arguments){
     Client *args = arguments;
     Queue the_queue;

     add_to_the_queue(&the_queue,args);
}

void add_to_the_queue(Queue *the_queue, Client *the_client) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);
    the_queue->number_of_people++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);

    printf("The thread %d is changing the counter of the queue which is now %d \n",the_client->id,the_queue->number_of_people);
}
```

Output :

```
The thread 1 is changing the counter of the queue which is now 1 
The thread 0 is changing the counter of the queue which is now 1 
The thread 2 is changing the counter of the queue which is now 1
```

Comment: the_queue is a local variable, and every time you call the routine, it's intialized anew

Comment: It's not clear to me how your multiple threads end up sharing the same queue.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth my threads are all going to the function tattoo_shop and from that they get to go in the function add_to_the_queue.

Comment: So each one creates its own queue.

Comment: `static Queue the_queue;` should help with multiple queues

Answer (score 2):

Your code is nonsense since `Queue the_queue;` is a local variable, not a shared one.

But had it been allocated at file scope, or as `static`, the code is mostly fine. Pedantically, you should not read the shared object outside mutex guards, because writes to the object from elsewhere are not guaranteed to be atomic. Slight adjustment to fix this:

```
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);
    int people = the_queue->number_of_people++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);

    printf("%d", people);
}
```

Comment: How could I make the_queue shared ? The thing is that I need to then get this data out of the function add_to_the_queue to perform tests in tattoo_shop.

Comment: @MaxUt: You define the queue outside the functions (file static variable).  That also initializes it to zero; your code increments an uninitialized variable, and you're just lucky that the memory happens to be zeroed (probably to prevent you prying at the data that a previous process stored in the same physical memory, but that is not guaranteed by any standard).  And all access to the queue needs to be mediated by the mutex (which, I note, is not defined/declared in the code shown, but must be a file scope variable).  Your printing code should be in scope of the mutex lock/unlock pair.